# Refresh ASP.NET page after download in same postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use DotNetZip Library To Create Zip and Download File as a Zip File then, I want To Redirect or Refresh Same Page in Code behind, How Can O Do that(In Same PostBack)

ex:

```
zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Redirect(url,false);
```

I want to Refresh Page After Downloading file,but It doesnt refresh if I use `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: Found Solution .I did that with using javascript,i had set time out in link button onclient event.                            OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"                      OnScript OnClientClick="JavaScript:AutoRefresh(5000);"

Answer (score 1):

Found Solution .I did that with using javascript,i had set time out in link button onclientclick event. OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" OnScript OnClientClick="JavaScript:AutoRefresh(5000);"

In Onclick event did call code behind function and call time off function in onclientclick event

function AutoRefresh(t) {

```
        // setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        setTimeout(function () { window.location = window.location; }, t);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.href = window.location.href;